# Unison - login over ssh with different username at remote server

Tags: ssh, unison

I am trying to set up Unison and am testing the connection. I run this command from the documentation:

```
unison /var/www ssh://192.168.1.102//var/www
```

but it tries to log into the remote server using my local machine's username. I've tried several things, but nothing works. I've tried adding username@ssh... and also searched for flags to use, but found none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a config file for ssh(`~/.ssh/config`) with the content

```
Host UnisonHost
    HostName 192.168.1.102
    User username
```

and then call unison with UnisonHost:

```
unison /var/www ssh://UnisonHost/var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

User [JRC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/124789/jrc)'s answer is almost correct. I'll just add a few details. Your command should be

```
unison /var/www ssh://username@192.168.1.102//var/www
```

or if you create a Unison profile in `~/.unison/` (which you should), it should contain the lines

```
root /var/www
root ssh://username@192.168.1.102//var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with unison's syntax, but usually SSH addresses are written like

```
[username]@[host]:[uri]
```

Or in your case,

```
pekasus@192.168.1.102:/var/www
```

Try that, to see if it works does the job. Don't include the 'ssh://' in front.

Comment: I tried that, but for Unison, you can't put username@ before the host. It has to read ssh://host